# Why can't I send data with QTcpSocket's write() method?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, network-programming, buffer

I'm trying to learn Qt with the documentation alone, and it's kind of tough. I managed to get a simple command-line chat client working, but I don't know how to send things. It takes about 4 lines of intuitive code to read from a socket in Qt, but for some reason I can't say

```
QTcpSocket socket;
socket.connectToHost("google.com", 80);
socket.write("hey");
socket.flush();
```

flush(); returns false, but I don't see why.

I really don't understand why this doesn't work and would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Have you implemented a slot to receive the `QAbstractSocket::error ( QAbstractSocket::SocketError socketError )` should an error occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After calling `connectToHost()` you need to have a slot handler for `connected()` or call `waitForConnected()` to wait for the connection to the host to complete otherwise your code is zooming right through trying to write before the connection is established.

Comment: I used waitForConnected()... it made flush() return true, but it didn't actually work (nothing showed up on my Java chat client).